# Properties of Orientation Covering: Lee's Construction

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, smooth-manifolds, covering-spaces, orientation

Let $M$ be a smooth, connected manifold of dimension $n>1$, and $\mathscr O_p$ an orientation of $T_pM$. define $\widehat M=\{(p,\mathscr O_p)\}_{p\in M}$. Then, $\widehat M$ can be made into an oriented manifold. To do this, define the projection $\hat \pi:(p,\mathscr O_p)\mapsto p,$ let $\mathscr O$ be an orientation on $U\in  \tau_M$ and declare the basis elements in $\widehat M$ to be $\widehat U_{\mathscr O}=\{(p,\mathscr O_p):p\in U\}.$ This assignment induces a topology on $\widehat M$.

No problems so far.

We have

$1).\ \widehat M$ is basically two copies of $M$, because there are two orentations for $T_pM$, which are in turn equivalence classes of bases for $T_pM:(X_i)\sim (Y_i)\Leftrightarrow $ the change of basis matrix beteween them has positive determinant.

$2).\ $ The orientation $\mathscr O$ on $U$ is induced by a chart $(\phi,U)$ on $M$.

$3).\hat \pi$ is a generalized covering map ($\widehat M$ need not be connected).

So far so good.

Now, paraphrasing Lee,

$4).\ $ Using $\hat \pi$ we can define a pointwise orientation on $T_{(p,\mathscr O_p)}\widehat M$: we have that $(\pi_*)_p:T_{(p,\mathscr O_p)}\widehat M\to T_pM$. We can define a pointwise orientation as the "unique orientation such that $(\pi_*)_p$ os orientation-preserving."

The orientation on $T_pM$ is either $\mathscr O_p$ or $-\mathscr O_p$. Is Lee saying that we pick one, compute the det of $\hat \pi_*$ and if it comes out positive, then we assign that as the orientation of $T_{(p,\mathscr O_p)}\widehat M$, and if not then we take the opposite orientation? I am confused.

$5).\ $ The orientation defined in $3).$ agrees with the pullback induced by $\hat \pi$ from $(U,\mathscr O)$ so the pointwise orientation is continuous.

I computed the pullback but have not been able to show that the orientation it induces agrees with the previous one.

Here is the paragraph from Lee's book that I am having trouble with:

[image]

I have seen this construction using top forms (Jeffrey Lee), and homology (Hatcher) both of which I understand (I think!), but I want to understand clearly what is going on in Lee's construction, because it is very basic which  means that I am missing some fundamental ideas, which I want to get straight.

Comment: For your statement 1), rather than say "$\hat{M}$ is basically two copies of $M$" it would be more accurate to say $\hat{M}$ is a *double cover* of $M$. In fact $\hat{M}\cong M \times \{0,1\}$ iff $M$ is orientable, otherwise it is a non-trivial double cover.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is only a notational issue.

In my opinion it is misleading to write $(p,\mathcal O_p)$ for the points of $\hat M$ because that suggests that we have a *function* assigning to $p \in M$ an orientation $\mathcal O_p$ of $T_pM$. I would neutrally write $(p, \mathcal O)$, where $\mathcal O$ is one of the two orientations of $T_pM$.

Via the map $\hat \pi : \hat M \to M, \hat \pi( p, \mathcal O) = p$, we obtain a topology on $\hat M$ such that $\hat \pi$ becomes a covering projection with two sheets. This is due to the fact that $M$ is locally orientable. That is, if we take an orientation $\Omega_U = (\omega_p)_{p \in U}$ on some open $U \subset M$ (such $\Omega_U$ always *exists* if $U$ carries a chart), then the two sheets over $U$ are given by $U_\pm = U_\pm(\Omega_U) = \{ (p,\pm \omega_p) \mid p \in U \}$.

Moreover, we get a smooth atlas on $\hat M$ such that $\hat \pi$ is smooth.

Now give $T_{(p,\mathcal O)} \hat M$ the unique orientation $\omega_{(p,\mathcal O)}$ such that such $T_{(p,\mathcal O)} \hat \pi : (T_{(p,\mathcal O)} \hat M, \omega_{(p,\mathcal O)}) \to (T_p M, \mathcal O)$ is orientation preserving. Intuitively, the orientation on $T_{(p,\mathcal O)} \hat M$ is just the *given* orientation $\mathcal O$ at the point $(p,\mathcal O)$. This procedure has nothing to do with any local (or global) orientation on $M$.

Then one can show that $\hat \Omega = (\omega_{(p,\mathcal O)})_{(p,\mathcal O)}$ is an orientation on $\hat M$. It is defined canonically without making any choices.

**Edited:**

Let $\mathfrak A$ be the smooth subatlas on $M$ consisting of all charts $\phi : U \to V$ with connected $U$. Connectedness assures that $U$ has exactly two orientations. Let us call an open $U \subset M$ *nice* if it is occurs as the domain of a chart in $\mathfrak A$. For nice $U$, the set $(\hat \pi)^{-1}(U)$ can be decomposed uniquely as the disjoint union of two subsets  $U_\pm = U_\pm(\Omega_U)$ as above. This decomposition does not depend on the choice of $\Omega_U$. In fact, we have $U_\pm(-\Omega_U) = U_\mp(\Omega_U)$ which yields the same two sets. Only the  *indexing* by $\pm$ depends on $\Omega_U$. By construction of $U_\pm$, $T_{(p,\mathcal O)} \hat \pi : (T_{(p,\mathcal O)} \hat M, \omega_{(p,\mathcal O)}) \to (T_p M, \omega_p)$ is orientation preserving for $(p,\mathcal O) \in U_+(\Omega_U)$ and orientation reversing for $(p,\mathcal O) \in U_-(\Omega_U)$.

The set of all $U_+$ and all $U_-$ forms the basis of a topology on $\hat M$ and it is easy to see that $\hat \pi$ becomes a covering projection with two sheets. An atlas $\hat{\mathfrak A}$ on $\hat M$ is given by the maps $\phi_\pm = \phi \circ \hat \pi \mid_{U_\pm} : U_\pm \to V$. This atlas is clearly smooth. That is, $\hat M$ has been given the structure of a smooth manifold such that $\hat \pi$ becomes smooth.

The family $\hat \Omega = (\omega_{(p,\mathcal O)})_{(p,\mathcal O)}$ is by construction *locally* an orientation. In fact, it is an orientation on each of the sets $U_\pm(\Omega_U)$. Thus it is an orientation on $\hat M$. This is true for **any** smooth manifold $N$ and **any** family of orientations $(\omega_q)_{q \in N}$ of the tangent spaces $T_qN$ which is locally an orientation. Observe that the *existence* of such a (global) family does not follow from the obvious fact that each smooth manifold $N$ is locally orientable. Indeed, there is no reason to assume that we can paste a suitable set of local orientations to a global family of orientations $(\omega_q)_{q \in N}$ which restricts to all given local orientations.

Note also that $\hat{\mathfrak A}$ is not an oriented atlas. It only contains oriented atlases.

Comment: I tried to use charts to do this. I took the points in $\widehat M$ to be pairs $(p,1)$ or $(p,-1)$ depending on whether $\mathscr O_p$ is positively or negatively oriented. Let $(p,1)\in (U,1)$ a basic open set in $\widehat M$.Then, if I take a chart $(\phi,U\ni p)$ where $\phi:U\to \mathbb R^n$ is a positive coordinate system (just means that $\det \phi_*>0$ on $U$, ...(continued below)

Comment: ... (and this can always be arranged), $\hat \pi|_{(U,1)}$ is a diffeomorphism so I can define a chart $\psi=\phi\circ \hat \pi:(U,1)\to \mathbb R^n$. (This is basically the pullback argument I guess). So, $(p,1)$ belongs to the domain of a positive coordinate system. Now if $(p,-1)\in (U,-1)$, we take $-\phi$ and repeat the procedure. Is this correct?

Comment: If the element $(p,1)$ is in the intersection of two basis elements $\hat U,\hat V$ in $\widehat M$, then  $\hat U$ must be of the form $(U,1)$ and $\hat V=(V,1)$ and siilarly for $(p,-1)$ so  giving $T_{(p,\mathscr O)} \hat M$ the unique orientation such that $T_{(p,\mathscr O)} \hat \pi : (T_{(p,\mathscr O)} \hat M, \omega_{(p,\mathscr O)}) \to (T_p M, \mathscr O)$ forces the charts that arise as in my previous comment to be compatible. Soreally, the construction of $\widehat M$ is designed to make it orientable because you divide the basis elements into $disjoint$ sets $(U,1)$ and $(U,-1)$.

Comment: @Matematleta Correct. I edited my answer.

Comment: Got it! Just to make sure I understand these ideas, I want to do a simple application: Let $p\in M$ and take a chart $(U,\phi)$ about $p$. Denote by $1$ the orientation of the basis $\{e_i\}^n_{i=1}$ of $T_pM$, and $-1$ by the opposite orientation $\{e'_i\}^n_{i=1}$, obtained for instance by switching $e_1$ and $e_2$. A basis for $T_{(p,1)}\widehat M$ is $\{f_i\}^n_{i=1}$ and by definition, the determinant of the change of basis matrix for $(\hat \pi_{(p,1)})_*$ is positive. .On the other hand, the change of basis matrix for $(\hat \pi_{(p,-1)})_*$(continued below)...

Comment: ...(from above) .. has negative determinant (because the orientation on $U_−$ is the one for which the map $\hat \pi_* : (T_{(q,\mathcal O)} \hat M, -1) \to (T_q M, \mathcal O)$ is orientation preserving, so $\mathscr O=−1.$  But in our case, $\mathscr O$ is given by $\{e_i\}^n_{i=1}$, that is $1$, so $((\hat \pi_{(p,−1)})_∗$ reverses the orientation.) Therefore, $(\pi_{(p,-1)})_*^{-1}\circ (\pi_{(p,1)})_*:T_{(p,1)}M\to T_{(p,-1)}M$ is negative, which means we get the familiar result that that if $\widehat M$ is connected then $M$ is non-orientable. Is this a correct approach?

Comment: @Matematleta Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 3):

To say whether $(\pi_*)_p:T_{(p,\mathscr O_p)}\widehat M\to T_pM$ is orientation-preserving, you need to pick *both* an orientation on the codomain *and* an orientation on the domain.  What Lee is saying is, use the orientation $\mathscr{O}_p$ on the codomain, and then pick the orientation on the domain which makes the map orientation-preserving.  Or, if you like, pull back the orientation $\mathscr{O}_p$ along the isomorphism of vector spaces $(\pi_*)_p$ to get an orientation on $T_{(p,\mathscr O_p)}\widehat M$.

In particular, then, as Lee says, at every point $(p,\mathscr{O}_p)$ of an open set $\hat{U}_{\mathscr{O}}$, the chosen orientation $T_{(p,\mathscr O_p)}\widehat M$ is the orientation obtained by pulling back $\mathscr{O}_p$.  But since $(p,\mathscr{O}_p)\in \hat{U}_{\mathscr{O}}$, $\mathscr{O}_p$ must be the orientation at $p$ given by $\mathscr{O}$.  So the orientation at every point of $\hat{U}_{\mathscr{O}}$ is pulled back from the orientation $\mathscr{O}$ on $U$.